# problems after running simple_arm_actions's node

Tags: robotic-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Groovy, Turtlebot2, Phantomx Pincher arm
rosrun simple_arm_actions reset_arm_server.py:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/turtlebot/exp1_ws/src/simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/bin/reset_arm_server.py", line 74, in 
ResetArmServer()
File "/home/turtlebot/exp1_ws/src/simple_arms/simple_arm_actions/bin/reset_arm_server.py", line 44, in **init**
self.joints = rospy.get_param("/simple_arms/joints")
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 452, in get_param
return _param_server[param_name] #MasterProxy does all the magic for us
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msproxy.py", line 117, in **getitem**
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '/simple_arms/joints'

Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155916/problems-after-running-simple_arm_actions%27s-node/) by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know anything about the turtlebot or the simple arm server, but it looks like it's trying to retrieve a parameter that isn't set (`/simple_arms/joints`); probably related to which joints to use.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1